# Error with QuickStart App - The redirect URI is not registered properly with DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

I've created a new developer account and followed the Quickstart instructions

The quickstart app is running with the pre-generated integration keys in ds_config on the following URL http://127.0.0.1:5000

The redirect URI for app created includes http://localhost:5000/ds/callback (these callbacks were automatically added for the Quickstart app)

I visit http://127.0.0.1:5000/quickstarthome and click on the first example, it redirects to the following url: https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&client_id=14413ab6-25fe-496c-bc8a-d6b87dc74f6c&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A5000%2Fds%2Fcallback&scope=signature&state=FA9F8538112E4700ADD39F7C9CC61E53&prompt=login#/username

The login page has the following error: The redirect URI is not registered properly with DocuSign

As you can see from the above URL, the server and the redirect URL - they match.

I've tried starting a new Quickstart app and get the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you're using python. we're going to fix it and you can try again right away. Please confirm which language you're using. We'll fix it and ask you to test again. Thanks!!

Comment: yes i'm using python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This URL was added. We had localhost, but didn't have 127.0.0.1 but now we have both.
You will have to try again from scratch (meaning you will need to download a new zip file) it should work correctly.